# How to use tee when using sudo

Tags: bash, sudo

UBuntu 16.04
Bash 4.4

In 4-bash-update.sh line 158:

```
cd "$drive00" && sudo -H -u myuser bash -c "timeout 2s ./binaryfile -gentoken" > "${save_log_dir}"/update-"${now}".log;
                                                                              ^-- SC2024: sudo doesn't affect redirects. Use ..| sudo tee file
```

I tried a few times and each time my file gets eaten.

Comment: What do you mean "eaten"? The command is **supposed to** truncate the output file -- if you didn't want that it would need to be `>>`, not `>`. (It's clear that as-written the code tries to open the output file with original, pre-`sudo` privileges, but if the file is "eaten", that means there were actually enough write privileges there to truncate it, so it's not clear what the issue you want to use `tee` to solve is in the first place).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need to use `tee`, just put the redirection inside the command that's executed with `bash -c`:

```
sudo -H -u myuser bash -c 'timeout 2s ./binaryfile -gentoken > "$1"' _ "${save_log_dir}/update-${now}.log"
```

If you redirect outside, your original shell is trying to open the file, but it doesn't have permission. Putting it inside the `bash` argument executes it in the target user's shell, with their permissions.

The `_` in the command line is a dummy value for the `$0` parameter of the shell. You need that placeholder to be able to supply the filename as `$1`.

Comment: Agreed; if you have permission to `sudo bash`, you probably don't need `sudo tee` at the same time. Some environments restrict shell access via sudo, and `sudo bash` isn't an option there. Also, if the file write is the only part that requires sudo access, it is more least-privilege to run the command that generates the output without `sudo` and pipe it to `sudo tee [-a] filename`.

Comment: Better practice to make that `sudo -H -u myuser bash -c 'timeout 2s ./binaryfile -gentoken >"$1"' _ "${save_log_dir}/update-${now}.log"`, so you aren't substituting data (filenames) into code (the argument to `sh -c`). Sure, the OP probably controls the values of `save_log_dir` and `now`, but better to be in good habits for when operating over uploaded/untrusted/user-provided filenames later.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy  what is the usage/purpose of the `_` underscore?

Comment: @nbari, it's a placeholder for `$0`, such that the following argument becomes `$1`.

Comment: @Barmar, ...am I correct in that the single quotes are an attempt to respond to my comment? (Even though there's no edit history, I don't remember seeing them earlier). If so, they don't actually protect against injection attacks; a filename can very much contain a literal `'` character. Consider `touch $'hello\'$(rm -rf ~)\'$(rm -rf ~)'`, creating a name which will perform an injection whether or not such quotes are present.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy They were in my original answer, not sure why you didn't see them. I'll use your version.